# HTTP OPTIONS request is being send, before actual request

Tags: node.js, api, http, express, http-headers

I am developing backend which is in node.js and mongoDB. The backend is based on API calls. I noticed one thing always that whenever i call PATCH API and DELETE API, i saw OPTIONS API with same url called just before the PATCH,DELETE call. I don't understand why it is happening? I don't know the technical terms for those methods yet so i was not able to find the reason over google, and i noticed the same scenario happening for GET API's calls sometimes also.

I don't know but is their any relation of this with the middleware code for allowing API access that i am writing below,

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Allow access request from any computers
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE,PATCH');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need of sending HTTP-OPTIONS request is defined by browser.
If your client and server both host and port equals, than there is no need to send such request.

**Examples:**

- 127.0.0.1:2000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 - OPTIONS will be send
- 127.0.0.1:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 - OPTIONS wont be send
- 127.0.0.2:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 - OPTIONS will be send

Basically, client asks server, if he is OK with that. And only after that normal request is sent.

Client send only HTTP-Headers, so this request method is much faster, than usual HTTP-Method including request body.

More info - [HTTP OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).

**UPDATE:**
The middleware you're using is allowing other clients to make requests to your API. In case if you experiment to remove it - client will receive error on OPTIONS call, and next request won't be executed. Just check how it looks. It is called [CORS error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Thanks for your response, i didn't get your first line of response completely. i never saw this behaviour on POST request call yet.

Comment: when you server and client are both localhost:3000, for example - you won't see this.

Comment: @Shaggie sorry for being not clear. I've updated answer a little.

Comment: u mean to say even is the localhost be replaced by IP, still if the port is same then it doesn't call for options???

Comment: @Shaggie I've added examples to make it even more clear.

Comment: Wow...good explanation...now i'm bit more clear about the behaviour